# Surface pro 9 usb boot ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, surface

I have a problem. The first time I booted from USB, Ubuntu installed very well. After kernel update I had an error. Couldn't boot, neither Ubuntu nor Windows. Then I reinstalled W11 with USB. The only system I can install is Windows. Ubuntu, Fedora, all not bootable from USB. I tried with a third party and also without secure boot. The interface gets stuck at the Windows logo when I try to install third-party software via USB. On another PC the USB installation works, only the interface refuses to load the installation. Do not know what to do next...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the linux-surface kernel, use a USB stick with Ventoy installed to boot, which will lead you to the mok manager to enroll the key. Once enrolled, remove the USB stick and boot as normal.

This is (perhap) a bug due to the latest update of UEFI firmware for Surface Pro. Mok manager from Ubuntu should be opened once a new 3rd party kernel is installed and a key is required to enrolled, but won't open under the latest UEFI firmware, which leads to a freeze at the Microsoft Logo.

The Mok manager from Ventoy(I tried it, and it has a much smaller size) or Mint LiveCD(as talked in GitHub issue) will open as normal.

see:
https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/1274